# SQL query for 'The account number is masked by an asterisk(*) except for the last 4 digits in both previous and new value.'

Tags: mysql, sql

table

```
ACC_NO      pre_val    New_val
123489432   123489432  123489435
123489532   123489532  123489435
```

I asked some of my friends but not getting how to write the sql query.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question, but maybe `CONCAT('*****', RIGHT(ACC_NO, 4))`?

Comment: Hi, so basically I want asterisk in both pre and new values.

required table

ACC_NO          pre_val     New_val
123489432   *****9432  *****9435
123489532   *****9532  *****9435

Comment: So just do the same thing with `pre_val` and `new_val`

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear but, I guess you want something like that(?)

```
 SELECT LPAD(RIGHT(ACC_NO, 4),9, "*");
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `RIGHT`?

Answer (score 0):

Extract the last 4 digits with `RIGHT()` and concatenate them with the asterisks that replace the first 5 digits.

```
SELECT ACC_NO, CONCAT('*****', RIGHT(pre_val, 4)) AS pre_val, CONCAT('*****', RIGHT(new_val, 4)) AS new_val
FROM yourTable
```